# How to publish vmware VDI though Citrix Web Interface

Tags: vmware-vsphere, remote, citrix, xenapp, vdi

I have a VMWARE Lab and CITRIX Lab and they work just fine, But is there a way I could
publish VMWARE VDI Through Citrix Web Interface.
I've XENAPP 6.5 and vSphere 5.1 and vmware stuff in place
I'm trying to build a solution where VMWARE VDI could be access via Citrix Web Interface

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally firgured it out, You can pull this off with XenDesktop and XenApp 7.5 where it give the option to choose the hypervisor...

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can run both XenApp or XenDesktop on VMWare, Hyper-V or XenServer, but that was not what you asked - you wanted to access a VMWare VDI via XenApp, right?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to directly publish VMWare VDI through the Citrix Web Interface.

The only way I could see this work, is if you install and publish the VMware VDI client on XenApp.

You'll then depend on both systems, in order to access VDI. Accessing your virtual desktop, you'll also be subject to additional latency, protocol overhead and possibly multimedia quality degradation, from running the VMWare PCoIP protocol inside Citrix ICA/HDX.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. But I've seen this pulled off with some good results. But I agree with the Quality degradation....lets see....